# rewrite .php extension

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Please how can I rewrite

Could anybody please rewrite this url?

http://localhost/display_news_cat.php?news_cat_id=14&p=2

to

http://localhost/display_news_cat/14/2

Thank you

Comment: I tried this but it's not working.---------RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ $1.php [nc]

Comment: Your latest edition basically changes the complete question... `:-?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have installed the rewrite module, you could put this in your virtualhost:

RewriteEngine ON 
RewriteRule /newsdev/news /newsdev/news.php [L]

Check this site for more information on RewriteRule:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

But I doubt this is the best way. The rewritemodule is usually not the most efficient way to do easy things like these. Depends on what other complex things you want to rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

You can do thtat with a .htaccess file

put this in a .htaccess file and place it in de root of your site
apache must have mod-rewrite on

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news.php news [QSA,L]
```

try this for all files

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(a-zA-Z0-9).php $1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

With mod_rewrite

http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-extensions

You need to work with the .htaccess file in your site root... you'll have to create one if it's not there.