# Please URL Rewrite in php

Tags: php

Please how can I rewrite

Could anybody please rewrite this url?

http://localhost/display_news_cat.php?news_cat_id=14&p=2

to

http://localhost/display_news_cat/14/2

Thank you

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592920/rewrite-php-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, this is normally accomplished with Apache .htaccess file rewrite rules.
Is you case this would look something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^display_news_cat/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ display_news_cat.php?news_cat_id=$1&p=$2
```

If this doesn't work, try checking your access logs to see what's happening.

Comment: Working but had to Change to ---RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^display_news_cat/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ display_news_cat.php?news_cat_id=$1&p=$2

Comment: aha yes, cut and paste error.  I've updated it for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

Create an .htaccess file in the site directory and add the following lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^display_news_cat/([\d]+)/([\d]+)$ display_news_cat.php?news_cat=$1&p=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

there are different ways to archive this, and it takes only 1 minute to find this out yourself using google. you could:

- use an .htacces file with rewrite-rules to let the apache do the rewriting
- map everything on localhost/ to an index.php, read and parse the request-string "by hand" hand show the correct site

Answer (score 0):

Also you can hold it in one script use GET to retrieve the values you wish and re-create the URL with that values. I don't know if it will help you..
Anyway a .httacess file will be much more useful for you.