# Converting URLs

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

**UPDATE 1:**

Sorry, what I meant was this:

I currently have the following url:

http://www.companyname.com/page.php

How can I convert that to

http://www.companyname.com/group/name

and

http://www.companyname.com/group/name/

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I currently have the following url:

http://www.companyname.com/page.php

How can I convert that to

http://www.companyname.com/group/page

Comment: First step => Go with some mod_rewrite tutorials. Come back with what you tried and where are you failing type of info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
RewriteRule ^group/page/?$ page.php
```

or:

```
RewriteRule ^group/(.+)/?$ $1.php
```

for other pages in this style.

Comment: Your first example works based on my update 1 in the original question, but I get broken links if the url has an ending forward slash "/".  Any idea how to stop that from happening?

Comment: Either that, or it should not display anything if the url has an ending /.

Comment: @osh: you can combine the example with a redirect rule that 301 redirects URLs ending with `/` to a one that does not end with the trailing slash. That way there is only one URL for search engines to index and anyone making a typo still ends up on the correct page.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the user to see `/group/page`, as it is *prettier*.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^group/(.+)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Would this still apply if i wanted to use a different last word? e.g. if i started off with page.php, would the above work if I wanted it to end up as /group/name?

Comment: Using this, /group/name would look at name.php, and the same for any other word you used after group

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of instructions on this theme.

For example

[Please URL Rewrite in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593527/please-url-rewrite-in-php)

Official documetation
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html