# Help rewriting url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please URL Rewrite in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593527/please-url-rewrite-in-php)

I would like visitors to access the page by typing `www.site.com/12` instead of `www.site.com/room/doorstep.php?page_id=12`

The IDs are many so i cannot create folders.
What is the code needed to do this?
I am trying to do this through `.htaccess` but I have not been successfull. 
Please help me with this.

Dennis.

Comment: Have you tried a basic .htaccess tutorial... I mean, you are not asking a question about a specific problem, you want us to give you the code that will make your application work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the `www.site.com/12` setup, is it makes it a bit tricky to do, as if you want to actually add a physical page called `1000` your setup may not work right (which may also depend on multiviews). Instead I would steer away from that and do something like:

`www.site.com/room/12` or `www.site.com/room/id/12`

The `.htaccess` redirect for that would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^room/id/(.*)$ room/doorstep.php?page_id=$1 [L]
```

That should give you the example you need to get the show on the road.

---

**EDIT**

What might even be better is just match a number:

```
RewriteRule ^room/id/([0-9]+)$ room/doorstep.php?page_id=$1 [L]
```

Which would only return true if a number was passed, since that is what your ID's seem to consist of.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got `mod_rewrite` set up in Apache, you can do the following in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ room/doorstep.php?page_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That's a bit of an overstatement. You should be warned by Brad's solution though. If you ever want a real page like `site.com/1234` which should not redirect to `room/doorstep.php?page_id=1234` you should try his solution (but be invited to accept my answer if it's good enough for you).